# Nextcloud behind Ngnix reverse proxy in a subdir url

Tags: nginx, docker, reverse-proxy, docker-compose, nextcloud

I use a Ngnix reverse proxy to keep several docker services behind HTTPS and in the same DNS.

Basically I want to access to Nextcloud with: `https://server.<my-dns>.fr/cloud/`
I have access to the initialisation page but all dependencies don't load (css, js, images ...) because the base URL seems incorrect.

For example my browser try to load `https://server.<my-dns>.fr/core/js/dist/main.js` while the correct one is `https://server.<my-dns>.fr/cloud/core/js/dist/main.js`

My others services work as expected but not this one.

### nginx.conf

```
events { }

http {
  proxy_cache_path /tmp/cache keys_zone=one:10m;

  # HTTP
  server {
    listen 80;
    server_name server.<my-dns>.fr;

    # For SSL cretificate validation
    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
      root /var/www/certbot;
    }

    # Redirect everything to https
    location / {
      return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
  }

  # HTTPS
  server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name server.<my-dns>.fr;

    # HTTPS configuration
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/server.<my-dns>.fr/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/server.<my-dns>.fr/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

    # Auth configuration
    auth_basic "Registry realm";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.htpasswd;

    location /glance/ {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:61208/;
      rewrite ^/glance(.*)$ $1 break;
    }

    # Other services ...

    location /cloud/ {
      auth_basic off;
      proxy_pass http://localhost:8181/;
      rewrite ^/cloud(.*)$ $1 break;
    }
  }
}
```

### docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  nextcloud_db:
    image: mariadb
    container_name: nextcloud_db
    command: --transaction-isolation=READ-COMMITTED --binlog-format=ROW
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=*****
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=*****
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=nextcloud
      - MYSQL_USER=nextcloud

  app:
    image: nextcloud
    ports:
      - 8181:80
    links:
      - nextcloud_db
    volumes:
      - ./data/nextcloud:/var/www/html
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      - nextcloud_db
```

I understand that Nginx don't rewrite the dependencies URLs but how to solve this?
I tried to change the Nextcloud base url settings but without success. I also tried this [Nextcloud in a subdir of nginx guide](https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/17/admin_manual/installation/nginx.html#nextcloud-in-a-subdir-of-nginx) but I don't really understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of *Shahriar Shojib* answer I solved it this way:

### docker-compose.yml

```
...
location /cloud/ {
  auth_basic off;
  proxy_pass http://localhost:8181/cloud/;
  rewrite ^/cloud(.*)$ $1 break;
}
```

### Nextcloud config.php

```
...
'overwritehost' => 'server.<my-dns>.fr',
'overwritewebroot' => '/cloud'
```

See the [Nextcloud documentation](https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/13.0.0/admin_manual/configuration_server/config_sample_php_parameters.html#proxy-configurations).

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
location /cloud/ {
  auth_basic off;
  proxy_pass http://localhost:8181/;
  rewrite ^/cloud(.*)$ $1 break;
  sub_filter "/core/" "/cloud/core/";
  sub_filter_once off;
}
```

This replaces all **/core/** to **/cloud/core/** in the response of the proxy pass.

> [ngx_http_sub_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_sub_module.html)

This may fix your problem but I would recommend changing the base url on nextcloud, see here:
https://help.nextcloud.com/t/change-url-nextcloud/52415