# Move nextcloud to sub url but put a public folder at root (with nextcloud + nginx + nginx-docker-gen all in docker)

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, docker, docker-compose, nextcloud

I have nextcloud running on `https://cloud.museumsstrasse.at` but since we will use nextcloud primarily for opening data to the public I would like that this nextcloud root url leads to a public nextcloud folder directly, e.g. to use this one: `https://cloud.museumsstrasse.at/s/Ytpcwos3o9o33kL` but so that the public would not need the url with the share sub-url but only type in `https://cloud.museumsstrasse.at` where this public folder would be opened.
As for logging in and synchronizing with nextcloud I would then like to use another sub url such as this for example: `https://cloud.museumsstrasse.at/internal`

Is this possible and how?

**My setup:**

I got nextcloud running with docker on a `Ubuntu 20.04` Server. Since other services are running on this server too, I set up a reverse proxy solution all with docker too including these images: `nginx, jwilder/docker-gen:0.7.3, jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion` which do the reverse proxy and also generate the config files for reverse proxy. The `docker-compose.yml` for all this is this:

```
version: '3'

services:

  service_nginx:
    image: nginx:1.13.1
    container_name: container_nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    networks:
      - network_nginx
    volumes:
      - ./volumes/nginx/conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./volumes/nginx/vhost:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
      - ./volumes/nginx/html:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - ./volumes/nginx-letsencrypt/certs:/etc/nginx/certs
    labels:
      - "com.github.jrcs.letsencrypt_nginx_proxy_companion.nginx_proxy=true"

  service_nginx-dockergen:
    image: jwilder/docker-gen:0.7.3
    container_name: container_nginx-dockergen
    depends_on:
      - service_nginx
    command: -notify-sighup container_nginx -watch -wait 5s:30s /etc/docker-gen/templates/nginx.tmpl /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    networks:
      - network_nginx
    volumes:
      - ./volumes/nginx/conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./volumes/nginx/vhost:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
      - ./volumes/nginx/html:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - ./volumes/nginx/nginx.tmpl:/etc/docker-gen/templates/nginx.tmpl:ro
      - ./volumes/nginx-letsencrypt/certs:/etc/nginx/certs
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro

  service_nginx-letsencrypt:
    image: jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion
    container_name: container_nginx-letsencrypt
    depends_on:
      - service_nginx
      - service_nginx-dockergen
    environment:
      NGINX_PROXY_CONTAINER: container_nginx
      NGINX_DOCKER_GEN_CONTAINER: container_nginx-dockergen
    networks:
      - network_nginx
    volumes:
      - ./volumes/nginx/conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./volumes/nginx/vhost:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
      - ./volumes/nginx/html:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - ./volumes/nginx-letsencrypt/certs:/etc/nginx/certs
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro

  service_nc_db:
    image: mariadb
    container_name: container_nc_db
    volumes:
      - ./volumes/nc_db:/var/lib/mysql
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
    networks:
      - network_nc_prod
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=XXX
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=XXX
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=XXX
      - MYSQL_USER=XXX
    restart: unless-stopped

  service_nc:
    image: nextcloud:latest
    container_name: container_nc
    depends_on:
      - service_nc_db
      - service_nginx
      - service_nginx-dockergen
      - service_nginx-letsencrypt
    networks:
      - network_nc_prod
      - network_nginx
    volumes:
      - ./volumes/nc/html:/var/www/html
      - ./volumes/nc/config:/var/www/html/config
      - ./volumes/nc/custom_apps:/var/www/html/custom_apps
      - ./volumes/nc/data:/var/www/html/data
      - ./volumes/nc/themes:/var/www/html/themes
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=cloud.museumsstrasse.at
      - LETSENCRYPT_HOST=cloud.museumsstrasse.at
      - LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL=XXX
    restart: unless-stopped

networks:
  network_ca_prod:
  network_nc_prod:
  network_nginx:
```

What I have tried so far is pushing the html code of nextcloud into a subfolder and fiddling around with settings such as `overwritewebroot` or `overwritehost` in `config.php` and various experimentation on nginx reverse proxying, but it all failed so far.
What I have tried to follow were discussions such as these for example:

https://github.com/nextcloud/docker/issues/401

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54716909/nextcloud-installation-in-subfolder-redirect-in-apache2

[Nextcloud behind Ngnix reverse proxy in a subdir url](https://serverfault.com/questions/998024/nextcloud-behind-ngnix-reverse-proxy-in-a-subdir-url)

**What does not work:**

For example what doesn't work is if I add to `config.php` these two lines:

```
  'overwritehost' => 'cloud.museumsstrasse.at',
  'overwritewebroot' => '/internal'
```

Then opening `cloud.museumsstrasse.at` with the browser would get redirected to `cloud.museumsstrasse.at/internal` but in the meantime the code in `/var/www/html/internal/<nextcloud_code>` got deleted and overwritten with nextcloud code in `/var/www/html/<nextcloud_code>` which I then can not open because the browser would redirect me to `cloud.museumsstrasse.at/internal` again.

However even if something with `overwritewebroot` were working, how could I avoid this redirection from `cloud.museumsstrasse.at` to `cloud.museumsstrasse.at/internal`? Because the former should be the public face and the latter our internal nextcloud side. Hence I want no redirection but two different urls for different purposes.

I assume if a pragmatic way would be to adapt nextcloud's docker image logic to point it to `/var/www/html/internal/` and then adapt the this docker's internal apache to show `cloud.museumsstrasse.at` while serving content from the public folder`cloud.museumsstrasse.at/s/Ytpcwos3o9o33kL` ? However I'm at a loss of how to do this...

Can someone help me here please?

Cheers,
Stefan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, I got it working - at the expense of quite some pain.

Firstly, what I tried and what did not work (or what I could not get working):

- Moving the nextcloud code into sub-folder (the nc image would always overwrite)
- Creating virtual host by the apache server within the nc image. I could get correct redirections, but the target urls were always visible, which I wanted to avoid.
- Creating redirections on the nginx reverse proxy layer.

Now, what I did instead was:

- 1.) "moved" nextcloud to subpath by symbolic linking
- 2.) recreate the reverse proxy stack with traefik

Details:

#### 1.) "moved" nextcloud to subpath

In order to reach nextcloud under the url `cloud.museumsstrasse.at/intern` (before I had it called 'internal') I did the following steps:

1.1.

Created symbolic linking within the container:

```
ln -s /var/www/html/ /var/www/html/intern
chown www-data:root -h /var/www/html/intern
```

1.2.

Then opened nextcloud in a browser, registered an admin user, provided db credentials.

This step is necessary since afterwards some config files are auto generated which will be modified in the next steps.

1.3.

In `/var/www/html/.htaccess` is the auto-generated code-block where `RewriteBase` must be modified:

Without this step I got an `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` error.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  ....
  RewriteBase /intern # <-- changed from auto generated `RewriteBase /`
  ....
</IfModule>
```

1.4.

Now it would work mostly already, except for the fact that the web login and client authentication form freeze (somehow related to the reverse proxying). This issue is discussed here: https://github.com/nextcloud/server/issues/19091 and to fix it, the following must be added to `/var/www/html/config/config.php`:

```
...
'overwriteprotocol' => 'https' 
...
```

After these steps, the nextcloud instance can be reached with the desired subpath `cloud.museumsstrasse.at/intern`

A helpful discussion can be found here: https://github.com/nextcloud/docker/issues/401

#### 2.) traefik reverse proxy

Now in order to show a selected public folder under the root url of `cloud.museumsstrasse.at` traefik can be used to replace paths on the fly while hiding the targeted urls from the visitor so that no matter what subpath is returned under `cloud.museumsstrasse.at` the url will always remain.

For this in traefik v2 a middleware must be defined. Since I'm using docker-compose only, I did this via these labels on the proxied service:

```
# defines the middleware:
- "traefik.http.routers.service_nextcloud.middlewares=custom_repath" 

# the regex which the rule should match (double dollar signs for escaping):
- "traefik.http.middlewares.custom_repath.replacepathregex.regex=^/$$"

# the replacement value (the subpath of a selected public folder):
-"traefik.http.middlewares.custom_repath.replacepathregex.replacement=/intern/s/63KFWGkziffJR8j"
```

#### 3.) The full docker-compose.yml

```
services:

  service_traefik:
    image: "traefik:v2.2"
    container_name: container_traefik
    networks:
      - network_traefik
    command:
      # an explicit reference to the docker network must be passed when multiple networks exist:
      - "--providers.docker.network=docker_network_traefik"
      - "--providers.docker=true"
      - "--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false"
      - "--entrypoints.websecure.address=:443"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.tlschallenge=true"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.email=XXX"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.storage=/letsencrypt/acme.json"
    ports:
      - "443:443"
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - "./volumes/traefik/letsencrypt:/letsencrypt"
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"

  service_nc_db:
    image: mariadb
    container_name: container_nc_db
    volumes:
      - ./volumes/nc_db:/var/lib/mysql
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
    networks:
      - network_nc
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=XXX
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=XXX
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=XXX
      - MYSQL_USER=XXX

  service_nc:
    image: nextcloud:latest
    container_name: container_nc
    depends_on:
      - service_traefik
      - service_nc_db
    networks:
      - network_traefik
      - network_nc
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.service_nextcloud.rule=Host(`cloud.museumsstrasse.at`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.service_nextcloud.entrypoints=websecure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.service_nextcloud.tls.certresolver=myresolver"
      - "traefik.http.routers.service_nextcloud.middlewares=custom_repath"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.custom_repath.replacepathregex.regex=^/$$"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.custom_repath.replacepathregex.replacement=/intern/s/63KFWGkziffJR8j"
    volumes:
      - ./volumes/nc/html:/var/www/html

networks:
  network_nc:
  network_traefik:
```

#### 4.) versions

Currently I got this running with nextcloud `19.0.1` and as seen in the docker-compose.yml with traefik `2.2`